# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API: How to Asynchronously Process a Request that Needs to Extract Results from an Asynchronous WCF Service Callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asynchronous

Suppose I implemented a webservice using ASP.NET MVC 4 that has a controller that exposes one method:

```
Response Process(Request request);
```

This webservice communicates with a middle-tier service for processing requests.  The middle-tier service contract service looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IServiceCallback))]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Process(Request request);
}

interface IServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Processed( Response response );
}
```

This service asynchronously processes a request via the matching Process/Processed methods.

What's the best way to asynchronously make a call to from the web service to this middle-tier service?  I'm having trouble seeing how to get the response from the callback thread to return to the calling client, when the callback method obviously returns in a different worker thread?

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: What version of .net are you running? Why are you using callbacks as opposed to just a return value? Why are you using `IsOneWay`? You do realise that WCF proxy creation supports the creation of proxies with `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX`?

Comment: Running 4.0 but I CAN upgrade to 4.5. That middle-tier service was created a long time ago and other services depend on it so I can't change the interface, i.e. use WCF AsyncPattern=true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use async and await. Read this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh300224.aspx

Comment: I've already read up on async and await but what I'm struggling with is how I would implement the async method that sends AND receives the response in a different thread.  e.g.    public async Task<Response> Process( Request request ) { _proxy.Process( request ); // now what?  The Response object will come back in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your calling code.

```
public void DoStuff()
{

    using(var proxy = new Proxy())
    {
        var result = await proxy.Process();
        Task.Run(() => Processed(result));
    }
}
```

Or this...which works with .net 4

```
public void DoStuff()
{

    using(var proxy = new Proxy())
    {
        proxy.Process().ContinueWith(result => Processed(result), TaskCreationOptions.None);
    }
}
```